# Survey tool with custom questions

Tags: gratis, survey

I hope this is the right place for this. If not, feel free to tell me a better place to post this.

Basically, I have about 100 clients, and I wish to send these clients a survey/questionnaire. I have a set of predefined questions, but not every client should get the same set of questions. For example, say the questions are A, B, C, D; then it is possible for the first client to get questions A and B, the second client to get A and C, the third client to get B, C, D, and so on.

For each client, I currently have an excel sheet with the exact nature of the questions. With this excel sheet, I want to make a survey with those question which I want to send to the client. This survey is rather basic: for each question it should provide a box where they can write their response, and also potentially a way to upload an attachment for each question. They will send us the responses back, and we should be able to extract the responses in a structured way.

I have looked into surveymonkey and microsoft forms. These look excellent, but as far as I can see, they do not allow me to customize the questions. I.e. I cannot send different questions to each client.

Does anybody know which software to look into for doing this easily?

Answer (score 1):

This functionality is a form of "branching" and is available for free in [Microsoft Forms](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-branching-logic-in-microsoft-forms-16634fda-eddb-44da-856d-6a8213f0d8bb), [Google Forms](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/141062?hl=en) and probably others.

#### Simple

The easy solution would be to create a question at the beginning which shows a dropdown of all clients or asks for some form of client id (e.g. their company name). After e.g. client CompanyOne is selected, you use branching to only show a subset of questions applicable to that CompanyOne. Similarly with CompanyTwo, etc...

#### Advanced

A nicer solution would be to have a unique link for each company, and then based on that link a subset of questions is shown. In Google Forms you can [use URL parameters to pre-fill a certain question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27904632/1256347).

I don't have a Google form to test it out, but I imagine it would work something like this:
You have a list of clients and their unique survey URL:

```
Client    URL
Mozy      https://docs.google.com/forms/etc/viewform?entry.MOZY=user_id
Mehmet    https://docs.google.com/forms/etc/viewform?entry.MEHMET=user_id
... etc.
```

Now the first question "What is your user id?" is pre-filled, and you can apply branching logic to show a subset of questions based on the user_id.